# Toggle Flash: hide&stop or remove? Which is better?

Tags: javascript, flash

I am going to be setting up a control that can hide and show a flash video.

I want to either stop it when its hidden, or remove it entirely. I've been able to do both, but which is better for the user.

- Hide and stop means its already loaded. But the flash object is still there, so I worry about it eating up processing power.
- Removing it entirely means no, its not there, but adding it again appears to send out a call to re-download the file.

Comment: Your browser ought to be caching the assets it downloads, so that it wont need to re-download the flash file. If flash is making XHR requests then it may be better to leave it passive in the background.

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning your system to work on *normal* computers, then in a *normal* usage there is no point to remove it and then reload. That would actually cause more traffic and "eat up processing power". Also the answer highly depends on your project, if you want to do it with one video, then I would recommend you to keep and "hide" it and not to remove. If it already downloaded the movie, then the movie will just sit in the memory, but if you remove it and the user wants to see it again, you have to download it again.

If you have a lot of videos, then I would consider something else.

Also, doing some tests and watch the memory and cpu usage could/would give you the real answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on task. If possible, removing is better, because flash leaks like hell.